# How to remove Node error when running GitHub actions?

Tags: node.js, yaml, github-actions

I'm fairly novice with Node and GitHub but getting a minor error with workflow .yml due to improper Node support.

```yml
name: Twit Air Quality Workflow

on:
  schedule:
   - cron: "30 6-23/3 * * *"

jobs:
  build:
    name: Tweet air quality
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Run Twitter bot
        run: npm run twitter-quality
        env:
          TWITTER_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_API_KEY }}
          TWITTER_API_SECRET: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_API_SECRET }}
          TWITTER_API_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_API_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }}
```

The error is relating to: actions/setup-node@v1
I have seen that we are now at v3 but unsure if there are further updates or additions that need to be made to the .yml file

Edit: "Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: actions/setup-node@v1" is the annotation on the GitHub Action

https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/

Comment: It's straightforward, just follow the latest documentation: https://github.com/actions/setup-node

Comment: It shows `@v3` instead of `@v1`, and `16` instead of `'16.x'`. I haven't tested if the syntax `16.x` still works, but I bet it does...

Comment: Thank you so much @joanis That seems to have worked and everything running as intended. Appreciate the help. 
That document didn't show to me so need to up my searching game. Thanks again.

Comment: I've just updated all our actions to remove these warnings (and they were all over, not just for setup-node), so I've spent quite a while researching and testing all this recently. I'm glad that work can help someone else too.